# How can I get the ID of the clicked document and show it in the console?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, onclicklistener

```
  const setupProducts = (data) => {
  
    if (data.length) {
      let html = '';
      data.forEach(doc => {
        const product = doc.data();
        const li = `
          <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4"> ${product.title} </div>
            <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">  ${doc.id} </div>
            <div class="collapsible-body white"> ${product.content} 
            <a href="" class="secondary-content">
            <a class="btn orange modal-trigger" >Get ID</a>
            </a>
          </li>
        `;
        html += li;
      });
      productList.innerHTML = html
    } else {
      productList.innerHTML = '<h5 class="center-align">Login to view products</h5>';
    }
  };
```

My idea is that i whant to get the ID by clicking on the document and then but the product.title in db.collection('activeWorks').doc(doc.id or product.id(I don't know whats right...)).set. I have no idea how to do this,please help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding an `onclick` attribute to an element. This attribute takes a string as a value and this string will be interpreted as code upon clicking. I added the `onclick` to the `<a>` at the end and your `<li>` should look like this:

```js
const li = `
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4"> ${product.title} </div>
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">  ${doc.id} </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body white"> ${product.content} 
    <a href="" class="secondary-content">
      <a class="btn orange modal-trigger" onclick="console.log(${product.id})">Get ID</a>
    </a>
  </li>
`;
```

Comment: I'm thankful for your help but it doesn't really work. I have added a question to my question :-)

Comment: *I have edited my question